# using with() method Along with find() method return all model instances instead one instance in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my **Product** Model:

```
class Product extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
        public    $guarded    = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

        public function product_pics ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\ProductPics');
        }

    }
```

And this is **ProductPics** Model:

```
class ProductPics extends Model
{
    public    $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable   = ['pic_name'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'pic_id';

    public function product ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Now I want to fetch a specific product along  with all it's product pictures in ProductController show() method . for that I write this :

```
public function show ($id)
        {
            $product    =   Product::find($id)->with('product_pics')->get();
            return $product;

            return view('main.pages.product')->with(['product'=> $product]);
        }
```

But contrary to expectations,while I use find() method to select only one Model, it return a set of all Products model with related Product pictures.

What is Problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you use the `get()` at the last part. Remove the `get()` and change the order of the methods bacause the `find()` method is returning a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` or an `Collection`.

So to explain what's happening in your case: it finds and **returns** the model with the given `$id`. Then you start a new query on the returned `Product` model with **static** method `with( .. )` and then `get()` to return all results as an `Collection`.

Maybe more clear in a programming style:

```
$product = Product::find($id); // SELECT * FROM products WHERE `id` = $id
// $product is now the model Product with loaded data from the DB.

$product = $product->with('product_pics')->get(); // SELECT * FROM products JOIN product_pics ON ... 
// $product var is replaced with the collection of all products of the DB.
```

Rewrite your method to the following to make it work:

```
public function show ($id)
{
    $product = Product::with('product_pics')->find($id);

    return view('main.pages.product')->with(['product'=> $product]);
}
```

Comment: yes , I try this already and works, but it was not accepted Logically for me. But should not first find model then fetch ProductPics?